# Single Caption for many subfigures in different page

Tags: captions, report

I have figures arranged as shown below and wanted to make a single caption. I needed all the three pages as figure 3.1 but what I'm getting is figure 3.3 which is latex counting each page as a single figure with a caption.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[firstpage]{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{changebar}
\usepackage[comma]{natbib}
\RequirePackage{import}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newpage
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
%\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{data1.png}
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{data2.png}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{data3.png}
\end{subfigure}%
\\
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1.\linewidth]{data4.png}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{data5.png}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{data6.png}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{data7.png}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{data8.png}
\caption{ Rotation curve of $H_\alpha$ and blue shifted Na D with offset velocity...}
\label{big-offset}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

A comment up-front: The code you've provided generates "3.2", not "3.3", as the number associated with the final `figure` environment.

Since you're loading the `subcaption` package, which automatically loads the `caption` package as well, I suggest you insert `\ContinuedFloat` directives at the start of each `figure` environment that's not supposed to receive a newly incremented caption number.

A simplified MWE (minimum working example) and associated screenshot:

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft, % remove 'draft' option in real doc.
               11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}          
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3} % just for this example

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{data2.png}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{data3.png}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{data4.png}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{data5.png}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{data6.png}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{data7.png}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\ContinuedFloat % <-- new
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{data8.png}

\caption{Rotation curve of $H_\alpha$ and blue shifted Na D with offset velocity~\dots}
\label{big-offset}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```